# How to Disable the combobox values on selection in multiple comboboxes JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I want to disable the values in combobox on selection for multiple comboboxes.
Like i have a four combobox1, combobox2, combobox3, combobox4 with values **Select**,1,2,3,4 and 5.
Now, if i select value '1' from combobox1, then it should be disabled from all other comboboxes. And then if i select '2' from combobox2, then it should be disabled in combobox1 and combobox3 with value '1' disabled in combobox3 also.

More clearly :

- Combobox1 - selected - value '1'
- Combobox2 - selected - value '2'
- Combobox3 - selected - value '3'

**Now the result should be :**

- Combobox1 - Disabled values - '2','3' but not 1/3/4/5
- Combobox2 - Disabled values - '1','3' but not 3/4/5
- Combobox3 - Disabled values - '1','2' but not 3/4/5
- Combobox4 - Disabled values - '1','2','3' but not 4/5

**EDIT**

If Combobox1 is selected with Option "Select" then it should disable all the other combobxes except combobox1 and reset all the values with 0 index for all other comboboxes.

But what happening with the code, when i select value 1 from combobox it is disabled for combobox 2 and 3, but when selecting value '2' from combobox2, the value '1' combobox3 gets enabled.

Here is what i have done so far :

**HTML Code :**

```
<head>
    <title>Language test page</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<select name="g1" id="select_g1">
    <option value="select1">Select</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>

<select name="g2" id="select_g2">
<option value="select2">Select</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>

<select name="g3" id="select_g3">
<option value="select3">Select</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>



</body>

</html>
```

**JQuery Code :**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select').on('change', function (e) {
            $('select option').prop('disabled', false);
            var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);

            var valueSelected = this.value;

            $("select option:contains('" + valueSelected + "')").each(function(){
                if(valueSelected === this.value){
                    this.disabled = true;
                }else{
                    this.disabled = false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This disable de option in other "select"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(e){

            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var value = this.value;

            $("select option").each(function(){

                var idParent = $(this).parent().attr("id");

                if(id != idParent){
                    if(this.value == value){
                        this.disabled = true;
                    }

                }


            })

        })
    });
```

Comment: I have one more thing to add to this. If i have select option with value "Select" in each combobox, then we have four values 'Select','1','2','3','4','5'. Now, in the above code if the user select value "Select" from combobox3, then this combobox disables this "Select" value in each combobx, which is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").on("change", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();         
            console.log($(this).val());
            var valueSelected = $(this).val()
            $("select option:contains('" + valueSelected + "')").prop("disabled", true);
        });
    });

</script>





</head>

<body>



<select name="g1">
    <option value="select1">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select name="g2">
<option value="select2">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select name="g3">
<option value="select3">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>   

<select name="g4">
<option value="select4">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>   



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works fine. But i have one more issue. I have edited the question for the same. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with this.prop('disabled', false) ?